# R: Counting number of consecutive hours per day, month, and year

Tags: r, dplyr, time, count, sequence

I have researched and tried many things. I am already using dplyr, tidyr, data.table, lubridate, and sqldf packages in my script.

Here is part of my [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI623.png). I am trying to count how many consecutive hours occur per day, month, and year. Some days may have two consecutive sets, such as 2 hours and 4 hours. I would like all consecutive hours, not just the maximum per day.

Ideally, the final dataframe will have year, month, day, and number of consecutive hours. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code I currently have which gives me doubles and only the max:

```
consec <- df1 %>%
  add_count((hour)!= 1, name = 'Count') %>%
  group_by(year,month,day)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'Date   Time    flow   year  Month    Day     Hour
        1991-01-01 8:00   4370  1991  01  01  08
                     1991-01-01 9:00   4370  1991  01  01  09
                     1991-01-01 10:00  4370  1991  01  01  10
                     1991-01-01 11:00  4370  1991  01  01  11
                     1991-01-01 12:00  4370  1991  01  01  12
                     1991-01-01 13:00  4370  1991  01  01  13
                     1991-01-01 14:00  4370  1991  01  01  14
                     1991-01-01 15:00  4370  1991  01  01  15
                     1991-01-01 16:00  4370  1991  01  01  16
                     1991-01-01 17:00  4370  1991  01  01  17
                     1991-01-01 20:00  4370  1991  01  01  20
                     1991-01-02 8:00   4370  1991  01  02  08
                     1991-01-04 9:00   4370  1991  01  04  09
                     1991-01-04 10:00  4370  1991  01  04  10
                     1991-02-02 11:00  4370  1991  02  02  11
                     1991-02-02 12:00  4370  1991  02  02  12
                     1992-01-02 13:00  4370  1992  01  02  13
                     1992-01-02 14:00  4370  1992  01  02  14
                     ')
    df$year=as.numeric(df$year)
    df$Month=as.numeric(df$Month)
    df$Day=as.numeric(df$Day)
    df$Hour=as.numeric(df$Hour)
    df=df[order(df$year,df$Month,df$Day,df$Hour),]
    

df$obs=ifelse(df$year == c("NA",df$year[-nrow(df)]) 
                & df$Month==c("NA",df$Month[-nrow(df)])  
                & df$Day  ==c("NA",df$Day[-nrow(df)])  
                & df$Hour-1 == c("NA",df$Hour[-nrow(df)])
                ,1,0)

    
    df1=aggregate(df$obs, FUN=sum, by=list(Year=df$year, Month=df$Month, Day=df$Day))
```